# How to escape quotation marks when initializing a unix/shell command in python?

Tags: python, syntax, target

I am using target.write command to write this line

```
line4 = "do echo "$i|$( geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat $i | cut -d' ' -f4 -n | sed -e 's/,$//' -e '/^$/d' )" >> $output;".format(name)
```

but i face the error :

```
  File "m.py", line 8
    target.write('output=/var/www/html/Result/{0}/RIPs.txt;\necho > $output;\nfor i in $( cat /var/www/html/Result/{0}/PWIPs.txt );\ndo echo "$i|$( geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat $i | cut -d' ' -f4 -n | sed -e 's/,$//' -e '/^$/d' )" >> $output;;\ndone'.format(name))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also i removed the code

```
| sed -e 's/,$//' -e '/^$/d'
```

but i got the the file without the ' strings after -d ?

any help ?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be wrapping a shell script in python.

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap a unix command / shell script as a string with triple quotes, e.g.:

```
>>> import os
>>> cmd = r""" echo "Hello World" """
>>> os.system(cmd)
Hello World
```

As @pts noted, slashes might not be parsed properly, so use raw string e.g. `r"""..."""`. see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Comment: This doesn't work as expected if the string contains a backslash (like the string in the question). For example, `echo '\'` prints a backslash, but `os.system(""" echo '\' """)` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the `r`, it creates a raw string literal. This will work unless there is a `"""` within your string. In that case, use `r'''...'''` instead.

```
import os
os.system(r"""do echo "$i|$( geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat $i | cut -d' ' -f4 -n | sed -e 's/,$//' -e '/^$/d' )" >> $output;""".format(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflows syntax highlighting should give you a hint: You are using `"` both for quoting the string to python and in the string itself - how is python supposed to distinguish them?

You need to either stick to different quotes for the string and its quotes, or escape the ones inside the string.